# Rostering problem - variation of the post office problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Suppose I have $N$ staff members. I employ each of them for 5 days during the week.  Each day, $i$, from Saturday to Friday requires $s_i$ staff members. I wish to maximize the number of staff who have two days in a row off each week. Each staff member is rostered to work the same days each week. I don't employ anymore staff than necessary on a given day. How do I turn this problem into an integer-linear program?

This is definitely a type of variation of the post office problem, but with a fixed number of employees.

So far, I have the following:

Let $x_i$ be the number of employees with the first day off on day $i$. The total number of employees with consecutive days of are then given by:
$$
\frac{1}{2}[(x_1 + x_2) + (x_2 + x_3) + (x_3 + x_4) + (x_4 + x_5) + (x_5 + x_6) + (x_6 + x_7) + (x_7 + x_1)]
$$
which means I am trying to maximize:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^7 x_i
$$

I am now not sure how to form the constraints.

Comment: @saulspatz two days off in a row.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows.

First, define the set $I$ of possible shifts with two days off in a row :

- shift $1$ :  mondays and tuesdays off
- shift $2$ :  tuesdays and wednesdays off
- shift $3$ :  wednesdays and thursdays off
- etc

Complete with other types of shifts $J$ such as

- shift $i$ : mondays and wednesays off

Second, define binary variables $y_i \in \{0,1\}$ that take value $1$ if and only if shift $i$ is selected, $i \in I\cup J$.

Now, you have everything you need. You want to maximize the number of shifts selected from $I$:
$$
\sum_{i \in I} y_i
$$
subject to

- You need $s_t$ shifts on day $t$ (among the shifts that have a working day on $t$) : 
  $$
  \sum_{i \in I\cup J | t \in i} y_i = s_t \quad \forall t=1,...,5
  $$
- You need a total of $N$ shifts (one for each staff member):
  $$
  \sum_{i \in I\cup J } y_i = N 
  $$